Retrieve the Numbered Bullet Number from Word Document Table Cell
We are working on an application which reads the MS Word document template having information entered in a specific table. The first column of the table holds the Steps number in numbered bullet list format. We have tried many alternatives to read the cell value, but it always gives the empty string. We are able to retrieve the cell value using MS Word Office Interop, but we want the solution with Open XML. Any help with sample code to achieve this is much appreciated.
We have tried to find the abstractnumId and levels but could not find the cell value.
